# Spring JdbcTemplate and NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-data, dao, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Is it advisable to use `JDBCTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` together with an idea that `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is used for inserting/updating while `JdbcTemplate` takes care of retrieving and deleting? Because I can insert objects by using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` as simple as shown below:

```
public long save(Domain obj) {

    String sql = "insert into domain(name,password,salt,dnspod_domain_id,status)" +
            " values(:name,:password,:salt,:dnspodDomainId,:status)";

    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    namedJdbc.update(sql, new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(obj), keyHolder);

    return keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
}
```

If I want to insert objects/data into table by using `JDBCTemplate`, I will have to write lot of code manually assigning parameters with `PreparedStatement`...

When it comes to retrieving, I can do it by `JDBCTemplate` as shown below:

```
List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM user", BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class));
```

No need to use `ResultSet` along with `RowMapper` to retrieve rows.

My concern is that if there are any performance issues using `JDBCTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` together.

Comment: You can, of course. But why wouldn't you also use the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to select. It provides the same method: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-. Side note: the question editor has a button to format code. Just use it (or just hit Ctrl-K, or just indent all lines of code with 4 spaces). Don't use HTML.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

You can use both `JdbcTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` whenever it is needed. `JdbcTemplate` is slightly error-prone, since the order of "?" placeholders present in query and order of parameters you are passing through either array or direct setting is matter.

Where as `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`allows you to assign names to parameters and map values to the parameters by name, does't matter which order you set the values.

As per `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` api doc,

> This class delegates to a wrapped JdbcTemplate once the substitution from named parameters to JDBC style '?' placeholders is done at execution time.

So internally api takes some additional time to convert Named params to `**?**' place holders, but this can be ignored.

My suggestion is if your query has too many parameters go with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, since its safe and error free else go with `JdbcTemplate`.